# Numpy - split a matrix considering offsets

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Given an `m x n` matrix I want to split it into square `a x a` (a = 3 or a = 4) matrices of arbitrary offset (minimal offset = 1, max offset = block size), like Mathematica's [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) function does:

For example, given a 4 x 4 matrix `A` like

```
1  2  3  4 
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

If I give 3 x 3 blocks and offset = 1, I want to get the 4 matrices:

```
1  2  3 
5  6  7 
9  10 11

2  3  4 
6  7  8
10 11 12

5  6  7 
9  10 11
13 14 15

6  7  8
10 11 12
14 15 16
```

If matrix `A` is `A = np.arange(1, 37).reshape((6,6))` and I use 3 x 3 blocks with offset = 3, I want as output the blocks:

```
1  2  3
7  8  9
3 14 15

 4  5  6
10 11 12
16 17 18

19 20 21
25 26 27
31 32 33

22 23 24
28 29 30
34 35 36
```

I'm ok with matrix A being a list of lists and I think that I don't need NumPy's functionality. I was surprised that neither `array_split` nor `numpy.split` provide this offset option out of the box, is it more straightforward to code this in pure Python with slicing or should I look into NumPy's strides? I want the code to be highly legible.

Comment: Similar questions get phrased in terms of rolling or sliding windows.  Someone might even find a good duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

As you hint, there is a way of doing this with `strides`

```
In [900]: M = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=(2,2,3,3), strides=(16,4,16,4))
In [901]: M
Out[901]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 5,  6,  7],
         [ 9, 10, 11]],

        [[ 2,  3,  4],
         [ 6,  7,  8],
         [10, 11, 12]]],


       [[[ 5,  6,  7],
         [ 9, 10, 11],
         [13, 14, 15]],

        [[ 6,  7,  8],
         [10, 11, 12],
         [14, 15, 16]]]])
In [902]: M.reshape(4,3,3)  # to get it in form you list
Out[902]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [10, 11, 12]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [14, 15, 16]]])
```

A problem with strides is that it is advanced, and hard to explain to someone without much numpy experience.  I figured out the form without much trial and error, but I've been hanging around here too long. :) ).

But this iterative solution is easier to explain:

```
In [909]: alist=[]
In [910]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     for j in range(2):
     ...:         alist.append(A[np.ix_(range(i,i+3),range(j,j+3))])
     ...:         
In [911]: alist
Out[911]: 
[array([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]), 
 array([[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [10, 11, 12]]), 
 array([[ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [13, 14, 15]]), 
 array([[ 6,  7,  8],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [14, 15, 16]])]
```

Which can be turned into an array with `np.array(alist)`.  There's nothing wrong with using this if it is clearer.

One thing to keep in mind about the `as_strided` approach is that it is a view, and changes to `M` may change `A`, and a change in one place in `M` may modify several places in `M`.  But that reshaping `M` may turn it into a copy.  So overall it's safer to read values from `M`, and use them for calculations like `sum` and `mean`.  In place changes can be unpredictable.

The iterative solution produces copies all around.

The iterative solution with `np.ogrid` instead of `np.ix_` (otherwise the same idea):

```
np.array([A[np.ogrid[i:i+3, j:j+3]] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)])
```

both `ix_` and `ogrid` are just easy ways constructing the pair of vectors for indexing a block:

```
In [970]: np.ogrid[0:3, 0:3]
Out[970]: 
[array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 1, 2]])]
```

The same thing but with `slice` objects:

```
np.array([A[slice(i,i+3), slice(j,j+3)] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)])
```

The list version of this would have similar `view` behavior as the `as_strided` solution (the elements of the list are views).

For the 6x6 with non-overlapping blocks, try:

```
In [1016]: np.array([A[slice(i,i+3), slice(j,j+3)] for i in range(0,6,3) for j i
      ...: n range(0,6,3)])
Out[1016]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[19, 20, 21],
        [25, 26, 27],
        [31, 32, 33]],

       [[22, 23, 24],
        [28, 29, 30],
        [34, 35, 36]]])
```

Assuming you want contiguous blocks, the inner slices/ranges don't change, just the stepping for the outer `i` and `j`

```
In [1017]: np.arange(0,6,3)
Out[1017]: array([0, 3])
```

Comment: @hpauji thanks, I like the `np.ix_` version and I thought it would be straightforward enought, but I can't get it to work on another matrix while specifying the offset, for example this `import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1, 37).reshape((6,6))
print A 
alist =[]
blockSize = 3
offset = 3 
for i in range(0, blockSize -1, offset):
    for j in range(0, blockSize -1, offset):
        alist.append(A[np.ix_(range(i,i + blockSize, offset),range(j,j + blockSize, offset))])
np.array(alist) ` fails with both offsets 3 and 1, how can I fix that?

Comment: I had to past that comment into an editor and line breaks to read it.  What's the purpose of this `offset`?  In `range` the 3rd value is the `step`.

Comment: it's the offset between blocks, like a sliding window stride. An offset of 3 for 3 x 3 blocks in `A = np.arange(1, 37).reshape((6,6))` would give only the 4 blocks that one would get from `np.split(A, 3)`. I expanded the question to illustrate.

Comment: I added a 6x6 version of one of my solutions.  It just changes the outer `range` expressions.

Comment: thanks, but the 6 x 6 solution was just an example explaining that I want a general block separation function with function for m x n matrices, as the OP states. `np.array([A[slice(i,i+3), slice(j,j+3)] for i in range(0,6,3) for j in range(0,6,3)])` fails when the matrix has 6 x 3 elements. I'll attempt to code a solution based on your post.